Proving that a recursive sequence is bounded and monotone
Let $a_0=2\sqrt3$ and $b_0=3$, and define two sequences recursively by $$a_n=\frac{2a_{n-1}b_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}\quad\text{and}\quad b_n=\sqrt{a_nb_{n-1}}.$$
This is an exercise in Jay Cummings (Real Analysis: A Long-Form Mathematics Textbook).
The problem presents two separate recursive sequences defined in terms of each other. We are meant to show that one is monotonically increasing,  one is monotonically decreasing, prove they both converge and then show that the value they converge to is $\pi$.
I have tried induction, I have tried to subtract successive terms, I have tried to first show they are bounded, to no avail.
A hint or the solution would be appreciated!

Please don't rely on pictures to convey important parts of your question, format equations with MathJax instead. This time, I did that for you. Please make sure I didn't accidentally change the question.

from the rest of the question I'd say $ b_n=\sqrt{a_nb_{n-1}}$  is incorrect, suggest  $ b_n=\sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}}$

@WillJagy I just double-checked, the picture (which was a photo of the book) definitely had $a_n$ under the root. From computations, replacing that $a_n$ by $a_{n-1}$ would result in the sequences converging to $\approx 3.22$, so I'm pretty confident the sequences are stated correctly.

This is called the geometric-harmonic mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric%E2%80%93harmonic_mean

This question is similar to: Proving Archimedes Sequences Equal $\pi$.. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for typesetting the question @anankElpis

As mentioned in the comments, a solution to the limit can be found here: Proving Archimedes Sequences Equal $\pi$.
So I will just deal with the monotonicity and convergence:
Method 1
Suppose $a_{k-1} \gt b_{k-1}$, then $$a_{k-1}^2 \gt a_{k-1}b_{k-1}$$
$$a_{k-1}^2 + a_{k-1}b_{k-1} \gt 2a_{k-1}b_{k-1}$$
$$a_{k-1} \gt \frac{2a_{k-1}b_{k-1}}{a_{k-1} + b_{k-1}} = a_k$$
And so $a_k \lt a_{k-1}$.
Similarly, $$b_{k-1}^2 \lt a_{k-1}b_{k-1}$$
$$b_{k-1}^2 + a_{k-1}b_{k-1} \lt 2a_{k-1}b_{k-1}$$
$$b_{k-1} \lt \frac{2a_{k-1}b_{k-1}}{a_{k-1} + b_{k-1}} = a_k$$
And so $a_k \gt b_{k-1}$.
Now $b_k = \sqrt{a_kb_{k-1}} \gt \sqrt{b_{k-1}^2} = b_{k-1}$. And so $b_k \gt b_{k-1}$.
Additionally, $b_k = \sqrt{a_kb_{k-1}} \lt \sqrt{a_{k}^2} = a_{k}$. And so $b_k \lt a_{k}$.
Hence we have established $a_{k-1} \gt a_k \gt b_k \gt b_{k-1}$.
Noting that $a_0 \gt b_0$, by induction, we have $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing and $b_n$ is monotonically increasing.
Method 2
Again assume that $a_{k-1} > b_{k-1}$.
Notice that $a_k$ is the harmonic mean of $a_{k-1}$ and $b_{k-1}$. And so immediately we have $a_{k-1} \gt a_k \gt b_{k-1}$.
Additionally, $b_k$ is the geometric mean of $a_{k}$ and $b_{k-1}$. And so we have $a_{k} \gt b_k \gt b_{k-1}$.
Now we're done by induction as before.
Method 3
Utilising the linked proof, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are equivalent to the semiperimeters of the circumscribed and inscribed $3.2^n$-gon on a unit circle. Then the monotonicity and convergence can be seen by sketching a diagram.
Convergence
Note that $a_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $b_0$.
Similarly, $b_n$ is increasing and bounded above by $a_0$.
Hence, both sequences converge.

This was exactly what I needed! Thank you for taking the time.

Thank you. I've fixed it :)

Also note that once you establish $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge, you can set $b_n = b_{n-1} = b$ and get $b^2 = ab$, $b = a$.
